# Is it possible to define an optional flow or exception-like behaviour in Java 8 streams API?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Let us have a stream of objects, resulting from a sequence of operations (e.g. mapping, filtering, flatmapping, etc.). Now I want to do a certain operation on them, but only if a given predicate is true. Otherwise I want to immediately return something else.

A simple example. I have a stream of different food objects. If all of them are edible I want to perform a cook operation on them and return the list of cooked food. But if any of them turns out to not be edible I want to immediately return an empty list.

Few solutions come to my mind, but I am not satisfied with any of them.

I could first perform an `allMatch` operation with `isEdible` predicate on the stream, but it will result in terminating it and I would need to repeat preliminary operations once more.

I could persist the collection that is the result of preliminary operations before checking the edibility, but therefore I need to perform them for all elements. Which is suboptimal, because it may turn out, that the first of them is not edible and `allMatch` would return much, much earlier.

Or I could design a hacky `reduce` routine, but it would also be unable to stop processing elements when predicate fails.

What I hope for is something like the code below. Is it possible with current API?

```
source.stream()
    // some operations
    .ifAny(food -> !food.isEdible(), new LinkedList<Food>())
    // other operations if previous step not failed
    .peek(food -> food.prepare())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: The biggest red flag here is you want to do an operation on all of the elements, given that they all match a `Predicate`. To do this, you'll need to iterate twice. Streams don't iterate every element for every operation, it's more that they do as many ops possible on a single element then continue. I think an #allMatch is perfectly acceptable here.

Comment: If performance is your main concern, I can not say much. But otherwise I would recommend to keep it simple and do the whole thing in two steps. If you try to force it into one pipeline by performing all kind of fancy tricks, nobody will undestand it, perhaps even you yourself after a week or so.

Comment: I am actually leaning towards two-step solution because of exactly that reason - clarity. Still, I wonder what the options (event slightly vague) are - for the knowledge sake. And sometimes there are tricks that become obvious and easy to understand as long as someone has shown them to you first.

Comment: You could group by a predicate and then test if the resulting map contains false (as key). You could simply filter -> map & collect, and then post-check that the cardinality of the resulting collection is equal to that of the source...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly what you wanted, but using the ternary operator will make your two step solution look cleaner, it also should have optimal performance:

```
return source.stream()
    .allMatch(this::isEdible)
    ? source.stream()
        .map(this::prepare()) // do stuff
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
    : Collections.emptyList();
```

Comment: Neat syntax, haven't thought about it. ;]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method I just cooked up. It's a class that wraps `Collector` and checks if each element passes a predicate along the way. At the end, if any element failed, it returns the default return instead of the collected return.

On the downside you still have to iterate through every element even if the first one fails the predicate, but on the upside:

- Only have to iterate once through each element
- Simple in-line syntax
- Easily integrates with existing stream and collector syntax and use cases.

So based on those I would imagine it would be worth it.

```
public class SatisfyableCollector<T,A,R> implements Collector<T,A,R> {
    private Predicate<T> predicate; //The predicate used to test each element
    private boolean elmHasFailed; //True once an element has failed the predicate
    private Collector<T,A,R> collector; //The collector this wraps
    private R defaultResult; //The result to return at the end if an element failed

    public static <T,A,R> SatisfyableCollector<T,A,R> of(Collector<T,A,R> collector, Predicate<T> predicate, R defaultResult) {
      return new SatisfyableCollector<>(collector, predicate, defaultResult);
    }

    private SatisfyableCollector(Collector<T,A,R> collector, Predicate<T> predicate, R defaultResult) {
      this.predicate = predicate;
      this.collector = collector;
      this.defaultResult = defaultResult;
      elmHasFailed = false;
    }

    @Override
    public Supplier<A> supplier() {
      return collector.supplier();
    }

    @Override
    /** Before accumulating the new element t, check it against the predicate */
    public BiConsumer<A, T> accumulator() {
      return (a, t) -> {
        if (! predicate.test(t)) {
          elmHasFailed = true;
        }
        collector.accumulator().accept(a,t);
      };
    }

    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<A> combiner() {
      return collector.combiner();
    }

    @Override
    /** At the end, check if something failed. If so, return the default. 
      * Otherwise the wrapped collector's finisher.
      */
    public Function<A, R> finisher() {
      return (a) -> elmHasFailed ? defaultResult : collector.finisher().apply(a);
    }

    @Override
    /** Make sure IDENTITY_FINISH isn't present, or finisher() won't be called */
    public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
      Set<Characteristics> originalSet = collector.characteristics();
      if (! originalSet.contains(Characteristics.IDENTITY_FINISH)) return originalSet;
      else {
        HashSet<Characteristics> set = new HashSet<>(collector.characteristics()); //Make new set so we can modify it.
        set.remove(Characteristics.IDENTITY_FINISH); //Make sure finisher() is called
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(set);
      }
    }
  }
```

And can be used like this:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stream<Integer> stream = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8).stream();

    //Create a list out of the stream *if* every element is even. Return empty otherwise 
    List<Integer> listOrEmpty = stream.collect(SatisfyableCollector.of(Collectors.toList(), (x) -> x%2 == 0, new ArrayList<>())));
    System.out.println(listOrEmpty);
  }
```

This currently doesn't handle exception throwing gracefully, but that shouldn't be too hard to add.

Comment: To process the elements you need to open another stream after collect. It has worse performance like the two step solution, since it continues after a failed check. Also it introduces a new dependency on SatisfyableCollector. For performance reasons you should avoid allocating new memory by creating a new ArrayList and use Collections.emptyList() instead.

Comment: Also, it is basically a duplicate of `Collectors.collectingAtThen` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.function.Function-) - another variant of the discussed two-step approach...